# Syntax for multiple negative lookaheads

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract texts that are between /nr AND an opening square bracket or comma plus space, like this

```
[A/nrf, B/cc, C/nrf, （/w, D/nr, ）/w, ，/w, E/p, F/rr, G/ude1]
```

I want both A and D. I have tried `(?!,\s)(?!\[)([^,]+)/nr(?=,)` but it only matches D. Could anyone help please?

Comment: The problem is your `(?=,)`, but what about B, E and F?  All of those are followed by a comma and space. Do you *only* want to match A and D? If so, why exactly? Can you show a bit more of your desired output?

Comment: Please add more details, examples and clearly enumerate all of your constraints for what you're trying to match. Is the entire text in brackets a string? If so, quotes are helpful to show exactly what datatype we're dealing with because it could be misconstrued as an array of some sort. Your parenthesis in the "string" appear to be non-ASCII--is that intentional? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You said `I want to extract texts that are either followed by an opening square bracket or comma plus space`  

What it should read is   
`I want to extract texts that are following  either an opening square bracket or comma plus space` 

And this is what works `((?<=\[)|(?<=,[ ]))(\S*)/nr`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry my original question was unclear: I want to extract texts that are between /nr AND an opening square bracket or comma plus space.

Comment: @Louis Did the answer work for you?

Comment: Hi @Louis, you should add the python code to your question. It will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match A and D, but according to the logic in the comment `extract texts that are between /nr AND an opening square bracket or comma plus space` this will give you A, C and D.

```
(?:\[|, )([^,]+)/nr
```

You could use a capturing group to capture what you want and match what you want in front and after the group.

**Explanation**

- `(?:\[|, )` Non capturing group, match either `[` or a comma and a space
- `([^,]+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ times not a comma
- `/nr` Match `/nr`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oefilE/1)